# How to read files with possible headers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io, formatted-input

Originally I have files look like:

```
1.4 2.0
4.2 2.1
5.1 1.2
```

The column number is fixed while the row numbers vary file by file. The following code can read those files:

```
fid = fopen("my_file.txt","r");
M = fscanf(fid,"%f",[2,inf]);
```

Here `M` is the transpose of the data file.

Now I get several new files with potentially one line header starting with `#`:

```
# file description
1.0 2.0
1.5 2.2
```

It is guaranteed that then header occupies no more than one line, and always start with `#`.

I know I can read files line by line to deal with the headers. I wonder if there is any way that I can make as little change as possible to my original code such that the new code can read files in both formats.

`textscanf` function seems to be able to take care of headers, but the argument to field `Headerlines` is a fixed number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your headers are known to be prefixed with a specific character then you can use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)'s [`'CommentStyle'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btghhyz-1_sep_shared-CommentStyle) NV-pair to ignore them:

With the following `test.txt`:

```
# A header line
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

We can use:

```
fID = fopen("test.txt", "r");
M = textscan(fID, "%f", "CommentStyle", "#");
M = reshape(M{:}, 2, []).';
fclose(fID)
```

Which gives us:

```
>> M

M =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to stick with [`fscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html) you can check the first line of the file with [`fgetl`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) and use [`frewind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/frewind.html), if necessary (because `fgetl` moves the file pointer), to go back to the beginning of the file if there is no header.

For example:

```
fID = fopen("test.txt", "r");

% Test for header
tline = fgetl(fID);  % Moves file pointer to next line
commentchar = "#";
if strcmp(tline(1), commentchar)
    % Header present, read from line 2
    M = fscanf(fID, "%f", [2, inf]).';
else
    % Header present, rewind to beginning of file & read as before
    frewind(fID);
    M = fscanf(fID, "%f", [2, inf]).';
end
fclose(fID);
```

Which gives the same result as above. If the number of header lines isn't constant, you can get into using [`ftell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftell.html) and [`fseek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) with a `while` loop to skip past headers, but at that point you're probably making things more complicated than they really need to be for this application.